# How to make the excerpt_more filter apply to the actual post excerpt?

Tags: theme-development, excerpt

In the get_blog_excerpt() function below, the excerpt_more filter works perfectly when the post excerpt is not present, however, when the post has an excerpt, I'm not getting the "Read More" link.

I understand that the_excerpt first checks to see if a post excerpt is present, which is fine, but I want the read more link applied to it too.

What do I need to change in order to make the excerpt_more apply in all cases?

```
function get_blog_excerpt(){
    add_filter('excerpt_length', 'ce4_excerpt_length');
    add_filter('excerpt_more', 'ce4_excerpt_more');
    return the_excerpt();
}

function ce4_excerpt_length($length) {
    return 150;
}

function ce4_excerpt_more($more) {
    global $post;
    return '...<a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">Read More</a>';
}


function get_blog_links(){
    global $post;
    setup_postdata($post);
    $myposts = get_posts($args);echo '<div id="menuFooterRecent" class="blog">'; 
    echo '<ul>'; 
    foreach($myposts as $idx=>$post){ ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <?php 
    echo get_blog_excerpt();
    echo '<div style="clear:both">&nbsp;</div>';?></li>
    <?php } echo '</ul></div>';
}
```

The code above is inside functions.php

The code below is inside archive.php

```
<?php 
if(is_category()){
    if (get_query_var('cat') == get_category_by_slug('blog')->term_id){
        get_blog_links();
    }
    else 
    {
    get_category_links();
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: Where is `get_blog_excerpt()` called (or hooked)?

Comment: From inside a function in functions.php

Comment: Could be caused by a plugin. I just had the exact same problem, my code in functions.php to change the excerpt's length and look is fine (tested in a clean wp installation) but it's been "killed" by a plugin, 'Event Calendar 3.1.4' in my case. It all works fine if i switch the plugin off. Try to give a look in this way.

Comment: Solved my problem using this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-excerpt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you're calling `get_blog_excerpt()` in your template somewhere?

If so, what happens if you simply call `the_excerpt()`, and then pull the two `add_filter()` calls out of the container function? i.e. `functions.php` would just look like:

```
function ce4_excerpt_length($length) {
    return 150;
}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'ce4_excerpt_length');

function ce4_excerpt_more($more) {
    global $post;
    return '...<a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">Read More</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'ce4_excerpt_more');
```

And in your template, you would just call `the_excerpt()`.

If that works, then I suspect the issue is that your filters aren't getting applied - probably due to being wrapped in the container function.

Comment: Chip, thanks for the tip. But moving the filters outside the container does not appear to have an effect on the script. It operated the same regardless.

Comment: get_blog_excerpt is called from a function inside of functions.php, which is in turn called from a function outside the loop in archive.php

Comment: So, you tried just calling `the_excerpt()`?